# Can Python remove double quotes from a string, when reading in text file?

Tags: python, csv, file-io, quotes, strip

I have some text file like this, with several 5000 lines:

```
5.6  4.5  6.8  "6.5" (new line)
5.4  8.3  1.2  "9.3" (new line)
```

so the last term is a number between double quotes.

What I want to do is, using Python (if possible), to assign the four columns to double variables. But the main problem is the last term, I found no way of removing the double quotes to the number, is it possible in linux?

This is what I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys,re,string,array

name=sys.argv[1]
infile = open(name,"r")

cont = 0
while 1:
         line = infile.readline()
         if not line: break
         l = re.split("\s+",string.strip(line)).replace('\"','')
     cont = cont +1
     a = l[0]
     b = l[1]
     c = l[2]
     d = l[3]
```

Comment: do you need to escape double quotes when they are inside single quotes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `csv` module (standard library) does it automatically, although the docs isn't very specific about `skipinitialspace`

```
>>> import csv

>>> with open(name, 'rb') as f:
...     for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True):
...             print '|'.join(row)

5.6|4.5|6.8|6.5
5.4|8.3|1.2|9.3
```

Answer (score 33):

```
for line in open(name, "r"):
    line = line.replace('"', '').strip()
    a, b, c, d = map(float, line.split())
```

This is kind of bare-bones, and will raise exceptions if (for example) there aren't four values on the line, etc.

Comment: Is there any reason why this is preferable to using a built in module for this purpose, as I've shown in my answer?

Comment: `shlex` is quite specialized.  It happens to work perfectly for this task, but it may be more important for the OP to learn some of the more basic and more flexible tools first.

Comment: though there are modules capable of removing double quotes a simple map function really does accomplish what is required and there is no need to strip the quotes as the float function will take care of that conversion

Comment: @gr8tech float() will not remove the double-quotes.

Comment: This is what I did list(map(float,[1.2,1.3,"5.4"])), perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: That's a list with two floats, and a string. The string has no double-quotes in it.  Try this:  float('"3.14"')

Answer (score 14):

There's a module you can use from the standard library called [**`shlex`**](http://doc.python.org/library/shlex.html):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> print shlex.split('5.6  4.5  6.8  "6.5"')
['5.6', '4.5', '6.8', '6.5']
```

Answer (score 9):

```
for line in open(fname):
    line = line.split()
    line[-1] = line[-1].strip('"\n')
    floats = [float(i) for i in line]
```

another option is to use built-in module, that is **intended** for this task. namely [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html):

```
>>> import csv
>>> for line in csv.reader(open(fname), delimiter=' '):
    print([float(i) for i in line])

[5.6, 4.5, 6.8, 6.5]
[5.6, 4.5, 6.8, 6.5]
```

Comment: it can do it in different manner too: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL

Answer (score 7):

Or you can simply replace your line

```
l = re.split("\s+",string.strip(line)).replace('\"','')
```

with this:

```
l = re.split('[\s"]+',string.strip(line))
```

Answer (score 5):

I used in essence to remove the " in  "25" using

```
Code:
        result = result.strip("\"") #remove double quotes characters
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest and most efficient thing to do would be to slice it!

From your code:

```
d = l[3]
returns "6.5"
```

so you simply add another statement:

```
d = d[1:-1]
```

now it will return 6.5 without the leading and end double quotes.

viola! :)

Comment: No, that's what `string.replace(), strip()` are for. But there are better methods to unquote a line of csv or whitespace-separated format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp, try something like this

```
import re
re.findall("[0-9.]+", file(name).read())
```

This will give you a list of all numbers in your file as strings without any quotes.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the most universal doublequote stripper is this:

```
In [1]: s = '1 " 1 2" 0 a "3 4 5 " 6'
In [2]: [i[0].strip() for i in csv.reader(s, delimiter=' ') if i != ['', '']]
Out[2]: ['1', '1 2', '0', 'a', '3 4 5', '6']
```