# Importing csv lines in python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a csv (test.csv) file of this form:

```
> name age gender grade
  A    1   M      85 
  B    2   F      95 
  C    3   M      95
```

and have the below code:

```
myfile = open(testcsvfilepath) 
    columnheader= myfile.readline()
    rowentries= myfile.readlines()
    myfile.close()
    for rowentry in rowentries:
        print rowentry
```

the printed row always start with '' and i dont know why. Did i miss something or is there anything i can do to remove it?
the result is as follows:

```
['"']
['A','1','M','85']
['B','2','F','95']
['C','3','M','95']
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you read from a file in python, it will appear in your program in between quotes because it represents a [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

you probably want to check:

> 5.6. Sequence Types — str, unicode, list, tuple, bytearray, buffer, xrange
>
> String literals are written in single or double quotes: 'xyzzy',
>   "frobozz". See String literals for more about string literals. Unicode
>   strings are much like strings, but are specified in the syntax using a
>   preceding 'u' character: u'abc', u"def".

Consider using the [CSV library](https://pymotw.com/2/csv/):

if you are concerned about quote handling by csv, there is an existing post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707558/can-python-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string-when-reading-in-text-file)

but the [documentation states](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

> Dialect.skipinitialspace When True, whitespace immediately following
>   the delimiter is ignored. The default is False.

Ex:

```
import csv

with open(name, 'rb') as f:
     for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True):
             print row
```

Comment: yup, agree with that , however, the problem here is that it gets an extra empty line, just quotes

Comment: please post the result in your post

Comment: see modified answer =)

Comment: tried the above modification, having '_csv.Error: newline inside string'

Comment: try: line = open("myfile.csv", "r").read().replace('\r\n','\n') to remove that nuance and then proceed with opening and reading

Comment: say i have this = ["",'1','2',3',], is there a function that just remove the whitespace entry without just starting at the 2nd entry?

Comment: string.replace(' ', '')  --- two quotes, not a double

Comment: it is a list though not a string

Comment: ah, then you want to remove the item from the list, list.remove(' ') - or "" if there is no whitespace